# iOS AIR Native Extension With OpenGLES Causes App To Freeze

Tags: ios, opengl-es, air, air-native-extension

I created a Air Native Extension for iOS that opens a GLKViewController with a GLKView inside to render some 3D content, this all works fine. When the ViewController is dismissed, the AIR App has stopped rendering. Interaction still works (so the app is not frozen), but the rendering has stopped on the last frame before the native extension's view controller opened.

This is code from my view controller's viewDidLoad method (this is all the subclass does):

```
GLKView* view = (GLKView*)self.view;
if( view.context == nil )
{
    EAGLContext *context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
    if (!context)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
        return;
    }
    view.context = context; //Removing this fixes flash!
}
```

When I comment the `view.context = context` line then Flash will continue rendering fine (but obviously, I no longer have a context and can't render).

I assume Flash is losing it's EAGLContext when the GLKView sets the current context and is not resetting it. Is there a way I can fix or avoid this?

I have tried to save the current EAGLContext before opening the view controller, then to reset it when the view controller is closed, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I had to save Flash's EAGLContext before setting my own, then restore Flash's one after I had finished drawing/setting up the context. This let Flash continue to draw without knowing that my view controller was also drawing. I ended up doing this using the old EAGLView and a custom view controller as it wasn't clear where the GLKView was setting the context.

Of course, it would have been better for Flash to set the context itself before it tried to draw a frame, like Apple suggest!